# Require to show Base64 as image in a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, image

I have PowerApp that saves image as Base64 string in a SharePoint list (multiple lines of text) and I want to show it as image not text. But I don't know how to do it.

I will be thankful for any help.

Comment: Your multiple lines of text field is plain text or rich text?

Comment: Plain text. I even tried rich text but it doesnt help.

Comment: PowerApps only saves image in Base64?

Comment: I am still very new to SP and powerapps too so i knew only about one way how to save image from powerapps "MyImageData: First(LocalImage).Url" But with rich text or plain text its still only base64 text.

Comment: do you want to display image in power app only or on sharepoint list view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is currently no such direct functionality to save image as a file in SharePoint from PowerApps.

But there is a workaround for the same to achieve this:

- Create button trigger flow which will convert your base64 image text to file, store it in library and set it's URL in your desired list item in SharePoint list.
- After completion and checking the flow execution, export that flow and change the JSON definition of the **trigger.manual.kind** from "**Button**" to "**PowerApp**". Import it in tenant. (You can find JSON file in exported zip folder)
- Open your PowerApps, and you will find our updated Flow in the list as we have changed its trigger to PowerApps. Use this Flow for further action.

Please check below references for more detail:

- http://johnliu.net/blog/2018/7/the-simplest-no-code-solution-to-save-pictures-files-from-powerapps-to-flow
- https://www.techmikael.com/2017/05/an-even-more-clever-workaround-for.html

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the add, edit or listing page to insert an image tag like below:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64, ***Base64String***" alt="Image from Base64" />
```

Comment: Not sure if i understood. I added those html tags into my "multiple lines of text" field and inserted base64 inside src but is still shows only text not image.

Comment: For this you will need rich text field field.

Comment: I tried this in my powerapps but i am getting empty field now. MyImageData: "<img src='" & First(LocalImage).Url & "'/>"

Answer (score 0):

If your SharePoint list item is a plaintext multiline column you can just use an image control and change the Image property to the name of your column. And it will display no problem.

Comment: that doidnt work . Can you provide an example?

Comment: Are you trying to show a base64 text column from SharePoint in a PowerApps application, or are you trying to show a base64 column from SharePoint in another SharePoint column as an image?

Comment: All my SharePoint / PowerApps work is behind a govt firewall so I can't share an example. If you want an image from a SharePoint column that is a plain text field you can for example use a datatable in your PowerApp and use an Image control. Change the property from SampleImage to ex. datatable1.Selected.'columnname' the image will display in the image control.