# Convert base64 string to PNG in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, digital-signature

I am capturing wet signatures [using this method](http://www.sharepointjunkies.com/implementing-esignature-capability-in-sharepoint/) in a SharePoint list and will need to convert the list item to a word document using the content controls. Is it possible to convert/decode a Base64 string into a png file, and store it in the same list? The base64 string looks like:

```
data:image/png;base64,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
```

Comment: You can create another column of picture/hyperlink type and add the image in it while using PreSaveAction

Comment: This seems very straightforward, ill give it a shot. Thanks!!

Comment: I want to try this. where can I find the JSON file? Thank You and Kind Regards,
KH

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using the Microsoft flow. Please follow these steps

- Create button trigger flow which will convert your base64 image text
  to file, store it in library and set it's URL in your desired list
  item in SharePoint list.
- After completion and checking the flow    execution, export that flow
  and change the JSON definition of the    trigger.manual.kind from
  "Button" to "PowerApp". Import it in tenant.    (You can find JSON
  file in exported zip folder)
- Open your PowerApps,    and you will find our updated Flow in the
  list as we have changed its    trigger to PowerApps. Use this Flow
  for further action.

**Similar question is answered in another SharePoint stack exchange thread:**

[Require to show Base64 as image in a SharePoint list](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/266856/require-to-show-base64-as-image-in-a-sharepoint-list)

**How to convert base64 to image using MS Flow**?

[Base 64 converting back to image using flow](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/base-64-converting-back-to-image-using-flow-to-send-as-email/td-p/144339)

**Converting base64 to image using MS Flow screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: thanks for the thorough response! however, our organization does not use MS Flow (not yet but we are in the process of migrating). Our only alternative is Nintex workflows. Do you know if this can be done through Nintex?